# How to approach simple form validation using React + Flux?

Tags: reactjs, flux

I started to play with react and flux recently and I wonder what is the correct approach when validating forms? Using react only I would handle it in view-controller directly. But since I use flux should I move that logic to stores to be handled?

Comment: No . It is better to create universal input component.

Comment: I would do validation within the component itself with `onChange` and perhaps setting the state to notify the user right away when bad input is entered.  This keeps the validation issue within the component itself, as opposed to handling it via dispatching actions, passing props, etc.